# TaskCanceledException using Task<string>

Tags: c#

An overview of what I'm doing:  In a loop, I'm starting a new `Task<string>` and adding it to a `List<Task<string>>`.  The issue is, after the string is returned, the task throws a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException` and I don't know why.  Below is a trimmed version of what I'm doing

```
public async Task<string> GenerateXml(object item)
{
    using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        //...do some EF dbContext async calls here
        //...generate the xml string and return it
        return "my xml data";
    }
}

var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
```

My loop looks like:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => GenerateXml(item).ContinueWith((t) => { return ""; }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)));
    //also tried: 
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await GenerateXml(item).ContinueWith((t) => { return ""; }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)));
    //both generate the same exception

    //after looking at my code, I was using the ContinueWith on the GenerateXml method call, which should still work, right?
    //I moved the continue with to the `Task.Run` and still get the exception.
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); //this throws the AggregateException which contains the TaskCanceledException
```

When I step through the code, it hits the `return "my xml data";` but the exception is thrown.

What I'm trying to avoid with `ContinueWith` is when I loop each task and get the results, it doesn't throw the same `AggregateException` that it threw with `WaitAll`.

Here is a working console app that throws...  I know the issue is with the `ContinueWith`, but why?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
        var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => program.GenerateXml().ContinueWith((t) => { return ""; }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); //this throws the AggregateException

        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateXml()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return "my xml data";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `TaskCanceledException` have an inner exception?

Comment: Nope. No inner exception, no stack trace.

Comment: You should be able to avoid `Task.Run` entirely, and simply write `tasks.Add(GenerateXml(item).ContinueWith(t => { return ""; }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted));`. But this should have no effect on the exception you're getting, or how it's getting handled. Can you find a way to keep track of the tasks, and determine precisely which task is failing?

Comment: @hvd I skipped the `Task.Run` like you mentioned but when I step through the code, it pauses on the first dbContext query and never continues.  Doing it the other ways, I limited it to only 1 item and stepped through it.  The `GenerateXml` finishes without any issues and as soon as I hit continue on the last breakpoint, which is on the `return "my string";` the `Task.WaitAll` throws the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the second task.
.ContinueWith((t) task.

To run the correct one, you need to refactor the code.
Split the line like this:

```
    Task<string> t1 = Task.Run(() => program.GenerateXml());
    t1.ContinueWith((t) => { return ""; }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    tasks.Add(t1);
```

You can refactor tasks like this: (for error handling)

```
tasks.Add(program.GenerateXml().ContinueWith(t => {return t.IsFaulted? "": t.Result; }));
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked but I ended up refactoring and changing the way that tasks are handled.

Answer (score 3):

As answerer Avram hints at, you are getting the exception because your list contains not the tasks that are running the `GenerateXml()` method, but rather those that are the continuations of the tasks running that method.

Since those tasks get run only when `GenerateXml()` throws an exception, if *any* call to `GenerateXml()` succeeds, then at least one of those continuation tasks won't get run. Instead, it's completed by being cancelled (i.e. when its antecedent task completes successfully), and so the call to `WaitAll()` sees that cancellation and throws the aggregate exception.

IMHO, the best way to address this is to stick with the `async`/`await` pattern. I.e. rather than using `ContinueWith()` directly, write the code so that it's *readable* and expressive. In this case, I would write a wrapper `async` method to call the `GenerateXml()` method, catching any exception that occurs, and returning the `""` value in that case.

Here's a modified version of your MCVE showing what I mean:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

        tasks.Add(SafeGenerateXml());
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        foreach (var task in tasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task<string> SafeGenerateXml()
    {
        try
        {
            return await GenerateXml();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> GenerateXml()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        return "my xml data";
    }
}
```

IMHO this is much more in keeping with the new `async` idioms in C#, much less prone to failure, and is much easier to understand what exactly is going on (i.e. by avoiding `ContinueWith()` altogether, you don't even have the chance to get confused about which task(s) is(are) being waited on, as you obviously did in your original code).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `.ContinueWith` as a way to recover from exception, you can simply add the `try {} catch` statement.

```
   var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
         var closure = item;
         var task =
             Task.Factory.StartNew(
                  async () =>
                   {
                      try
                      {
                          return await GenerateXml(closure);
                      }
                      catch (Exception exception)
                      {
                              //log
                              return "";
                      }
                  }).Unwrap();
         tasks.Add(task);
     }
     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

However if I were you I'd hide this logic into the `GenerateXml` method. As long as you consider the default value (empty string here) as a valid one it should be fine.

```
var tasks = items.Select(item => Task.Run(() => GenerateXml(item))).ToList();
```